# Silverlight RadGridView refresh

Tags: silverlight, refresh, radgridview

I'm deleting a user from my GridView, but when I delete it. I first need to refresh my page to see the result.

Anybody any idea?

This is where I try to rebind the datasource

```
if (e.PropertyName == "deleted")
            {
                RadGridView1.ItemsSource = null;
                RadGridView1.DataContext = null;
                RadGridView1.DataContext = _viewModel;
                _viewModel.GetCovrUsers();


                RadGridView1.ItemsSource = _viewModel.CovrUsers;
                this._viewModel.PropertyChanged -= _viewModel_PropertyChanged;

            }
```

Comment: You can use ObservableCollection class and when you delete an item from a collection of this type, the UI will be updated respectivly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Inotify Property change.

Comment: Please give further details about how to do that.